# Send to Tomboy Context Menu

Tags: tomboy

Is there any way to add an option to right click menus for text files and/or highlighted text to "send to Tomboy" so that it would create a new note with the contents of the text file or highlighted text as the contents of the new note?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I do it:

install Gnome-Do

install the Tomboy plug-in, in Gnome-Do

highlight text

bring up Gnome-Do, begin typing in "New Tomboy Note" (it'll fill in the rest for you)

And voila: a new Tomboy note with your highlighted text already included.

Comment: Brilliant. Since I already use Gnome-Do, this is perfect, thanks!